# rsync -a and -L conflict?

Tags: rsync, network-attached-storage, copy, symbolic-link

I'm working on multiple servers and need to copy a large amount of data from one (production) to another (staging). The source server (production) has a NAS for shared files, that are accessed via symlinks.

`rsync -aL --delete production-2::www/html /var/www/ > /var/log/assets-sync.log`

In the log I get the following output:

```
symlink has no referent: "/html/share" (in www)
symlink has no referent: "/html/files" (in www)
symlink has no referent: "/html/assets" (in www)
```

Those are all symlinks. Does that mean I have no access to the NAS? And do [-a](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html) and [-L](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html) conflict in what they *want* to deliver?

Comment: Does the `--no-l` option help?

Comment: @LeonardChallis, it does. So I should probably turn to IT again, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LeonardChallis suggested and a basic (`--no-l`) rsync worked, I turned to the server guys and they updated my permissions.